# Persistent sorted selection QCombobox-QCompleter popup

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qsortfilterproxymodel, qcompleter

I have a custom class derived from `QCombobox` with an underlying custom list model (derived from `QAbstractListModel`). The model allows the user make a multiple selection from the options (by checking members). The combobox is created from a delegate (derived from `QItemDelegate`) that works over a `QAbstractTableModel` derived instance. The idea is that from the selection, the table model will store the selection as list containing the selection members, and display it as a string representation of the list.

So far my implementation works, but I havent been able to accomplish two things:

1. After the user inserts text on the completer, the resulting list shown is not alphabetically sorted (on the completer's popup).
2. Every time that I click on the completer's output list (the popup) the view hides/closes (I'm not sure which one) which prevents selecting multiple items at a time.

Here is a short (pyside) example of my implementation:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MyCombobox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyCombobox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setEditable(True)

        self.filter = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.filter.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        self.completer = QCompleter(self.filter, self)
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.completer.setModelSorting(QCompleter.CaseInsensitivelySortedModel)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)


        #signals
        self.activated.connect(self._comboActivated)
        self.lineEdit().textEdited[unicode].connect(self.filter.setFilterFixedString)
        self.completer.activated['QModelIndex'].connect(self._completerActivated)

        self._pressed = True

    def _completerActivated(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
           self._itemPressed(index)


    def setModel(self, model):
        super(MyCombobox, self).setModel(model)
        self.filter.setSourceModel(model)
        self.completer.setModel(self.filter)

    def _itemPressed(self, index):
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()
        index2 = self.filter.index(row, col)
        index = self.filter.mapToSource(index2)
        model = self.model()
        state = model.data(index, role = Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            model.setData(index, Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self._pressed = True
            return
        elif state == Qt.Unchecked:
            model.setData(index, Qt.Checked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self._pressed = True
            return
        else:
            self._pressed = False
            return

      def _comboActivated(self, pos):
         model  = self.model()
         index = model.index(pos, 0)
         state = model.data(index, role = Qt.CheckStateRole)
         if state == Qt.Checked:
             model.setData(index, Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
             self._pressed = True
             return
         elif state == Qt.Unchecked:
             model.setData(index, Qt.Checked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
             self._pressed = True
             return
         else:
             self._pressed = False
             return


    def hidePopup(self):
        if not self._pressed:
            super(MyCombobox, self).hidePopup()
            self._pressed = True
        else:
            self._pressed = False

class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        cb = MyCombobox(parent)
        tableModel = index.model()
        sel = tableModel._table[0][0]
        model = MyModel(parent)

        for k, name in enumerate(model._base):            
            model._checked[k] = name in sel 
        cb.setModel(model)
        return cb

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        mymodel = editor.model()
        sel = mymodel._checked
        base = mymodel._base
        myselection = [ name for k, name in enumerate(base) if sel[k] ]
        model.setData(index, myselection, role = Qt.DisplayRole)

class MyModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._base = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
        self._checked = [False for k in range(len(self._base))]

    def rowCount(self, index = None):
        return len(self._base)

    def data(self, index, role = Qt.DisplayRole):
        i = index.row()
        if 0 <= i < self.rowCount():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return self._base[i]
            elif role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
                if self._checked[i]:
                    return Qt.Checked
                else:
                    return Qt.Unchecked
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

    def setData(self, index, value, role = Qt.CheckStateRole):
        i = index.row()
        if 0 <= i < self.rowCount():
            if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
                self._checked[i] = value == Qt.Checked
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                return True
            else:
                return super(MyModel, self).setData(index, value, role)
        else:
            return False


    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable

class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, table, parent = None):
        super(MyTableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._table = table

    def rowCount(self, index = None):
        return len(self._table)

    def columnCount(self, index = None):
        if self._table: return len(self._table[0])
        return 0

    def data(self, index, role = Qt.DisplayRole):
        i, j = index.row(), index.column()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return unicode(self._table[i][j])

    def setData(self, index, value, role = Qt.DisplayRole):
        i, j = index.row(), index.column()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            self._table[i][j] = value

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication("test")
    tableView = QTableView()
    model = MyTableModel([[["numbers"]]])
    tableView.setModel(model)
    delegate = MyDelegate(tableView)
    tableView.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    tableView.show();
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Let's say you select several items in the QComBoBox popup that should be shown in that item in the QTableView?

Comment: @eyllanesc: yes. In the example, if you select "one" and "three" the corresponding cell in the qtableview will show '[one, three]'. But, as I said, that works fine. Actually the selection also works on the filtered list, but  it must be carried out one item at a time (because each click closes/hides the completer popup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found  solutions for both problems.

First, for the sorting on the completer output: I connected the `QLineEdit.textEdited` signal to a custom slot in the combobox. This slot forces the `QSortFilterProxyModel`instance to sort the underlying model by column 0. Not pretty, but works.

Second, for the "clicking" issue on the completer popup: This was a headcache. After hours playing around events and filters I realized that the mouse realease event on the view (the popup) was emitting the clicked signal (thanks to the docs for that) and, I believe, this signal was connected to the "hide" slot of the view. So my solution is an ugly hack, but again, it works. I wrote my own view derived from `QListView` and override the `mouseReleaseEvent` method on which I block all signals an then handle the event. In order to achieve this I had to pass the combobox instance my view class.

Here are the classes that were modified or added to the initial posted code in order to work:

```
class MyCombobox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyCombobox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setEditable(True)

        self.filter = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.filter.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        self.completer = QCompleter(self.filter, self)
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.completer.setModelSorting(QCompleter.CaseInsensitivelySortedModel)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)

        # signals
        self.activated.connect(self._comboActivated)
        self.lineEdit().textEdited[unicode].connect(self.filter.setFilterFixedString)
        self.lineEdit().textEdited[unicode].connect(self._sort)
        self.completer.activated['QModelIndex'].connect(self._completerActivated)

        mlview = MyListView(self)
        mlview.setEditTriggers(self.view().editTriggers())
        self.completer.setPopup(mlview)

        self._pressed = True

    def _completerActivated(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            self._itemPressed(index)


    def setModel(self, model):
        super(MyCombobox, self).setModel(model)
        self.filter.setSourceModel(model)
        self.completer.setModel(self.filter)


    def _itemPressed(self, index):
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()
        index2 = self.filter.index(row, col)
        index = self.filter.mapToSource(index2)
        model = self.model()
        state = model.data(index, role = Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            model.setData(index, Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self._pressed = True
            return
        elif state == Qt.Unchecked:
            model.setData(index, Qt.Checked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self._pressed = True
            return
        else:
            self._pressed = False
            return

    def _comboActivated(self, pos):
        model  = self.model()
        index = model.index(pos, 0)
        state = model.data(index, role = Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            model.setData(index, Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self._pressed = True
            return
        elif state == Qt.Unchecked:
            model.setData(index, Qt.Checked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self._pressed = True
            return
        else:
            self._pressed = False
            return

    def _sort(self, arg = None):
        self.filter.sort(0)

    def hidePopup(self):
        if not self._pressed:
            super(MyCombobox, self).hidePopup()
            self._pressed = True
        else:
            self._pressed = False

class MyListView(QListView):
    def __init__(self, widget, parent = None):
        super(MyListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self._widget = widget
        self.setSelectionMode(QListView.SingleSelection)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QListView.SelectItems)


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.blockSignals(True)
        super(MyListView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.blockSignals(False)
        index = self.currentIndex()
        if not index.isValid(): return
        self._widget._itemPressed(index)
```